# How would I use rtmpdump to download this stream?

Tags: rtmp

I'm new to rtmpdump and trying to learn. Any ideas how I could go about downloading this stream using rtmpdump?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://castalba.tv/js/jwplayer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("mediaspace").setup({
        'flashplayer': "http://static.castalba.tv/player.swf",
        'width': '650',
        'height': '400',
        'allowfullscreen':'true',
        'allowscriptaccess':'always',
        'wmode':'opaque',
        'controlbar':'over',
        'dock':'true',
        'dock.position':'left',
        'mute':'false',
        'stretching':'uniform',
        'autostart': 'true',
        'rtmp.subscribe': 'true',
        'file': 'ChelTV_Ch01_1000k@26291',
        'streamer': 'rtmpe://cp96798.live.edgefcs.net/live/',
        'rtmp.tunneling': 'false',
        'logo.file':'http://castalba.tv/images/playerlogo.png',
        'logo.hide':'false',
        'logo.position':'top-right',
        'logo.link':'http://castalba.tv',
        'abouttext':'CastAlba.TV - Stream Live Video',
        'aboutlink':'http://castalba.tv',
        'skin':'http://static.castalba.tv/bluez.zip'
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 12):

Based on [Emre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17404343/624466) and for those who want to save mp4 files with ffmpeg (rather than flv), you can use the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtmp://domain.com/path/to/video.mp4" -vcodec copy -acodec copy out.mp4
```

Comment: Also for transcoding / transrating operation it will be extended as 
ffmpeg -i "stream_link" -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental -s WidthxHeight -b:v BitrateOfVideoInteger -ac AudioChannelInteger -ar AudioRateInteger -f mp4 emre.mp4 or restream it with -f flv rtmp://...

Answer (score 9):

I was unable to stream the url, mentioned in the above code snippet, anyways How I do in my Ubuntu system is:

`$ sudo apt-get install rtmpdump`

This installs rtmpdump. 
And then to download a rtmp stream to a file 'downloaded_file.mp4', I use:

`$ rtmpdump -r rtmp://example.com/path/to/video -o downloaded_file.mp4`

-r is followed by the rtmp stream and -o is followed by a filename to which the stream will be  saved.

Answer (score 7):

You can save live stream with ffmpeg , similar to rtmp dump.
Download zeranoe ffmpeg build for windows or linux .
Reach the dir with cmd line .

```
ffmpeg -i "stream_link" -y -f flv emre.flv
```

where the stream_link can be udp:// ... rtmp://... rtsp://... http://...

Answer (score 4):

For Google Chrome i have developed an extension, can help you for capture any streaming link.
This is good assistent, the name is [Grab Any Media](http://grabanymedia.altervista.org/), i hope help you to capture this link, on the main site you can find more video tutorial

Answer (score 1):

If the stream is **Live** then you have to use **-v** switch

For example if a sample url is *rtmp://serverip/live/streamname* then use the following commandline of rtmpdump to start the download of **Live** stream

```
rtmpdump -r "rtmp://serverip/live/streamname" -o "anyfileNameforOutput.mp4" -v
```

Please note that you can view all the detail commandline parameters of **rtmpdump** by typing following in command line

```
rtmpdump --help
```

You can download **RTMPDUMP** using [this link](https://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/).

Answer (score 0):

Use rtmp explorer to view the page.
http://www.videohelp.com/tools/RTMPExplorer